# Objective C: converting hex (NSInline) to decimal per byte

Tags: objective-c

I'm converting a hex `characteristic.value` (NSinline) to decimal.

This piece of data is the following: `<d1448fe0 a1b1c827 efecdf87 a05b1907 5e4e62ec>` which is 20 bytes. I want to then store each byte in an array of size 20. I'm curious if there is a more efficient way to parse this one byte at a time. My current code pasted below is working, but it's slow given my sampling rate is about 250 Hz.

I put the hex value into a string then into an array of chars then parse loop through the whole thing.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

```
            int xval[20];
            NSString *val = @"";
            val = [val stringByAppendingFormat: @"%@",characteristic.value];

            const char *c = [val UTF8String];
            int number = [temp intValue];
            int counter_filler = 0;
            NSString *toFill = @"";
            int xval_counter = 0;
            unsigned binar;


            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(c);i++)
            {
                if (c[i] != '<' && c[i] != '>' && c[i] != ' ')
                {
                if (counter_filler == 2)
                {
                    counter_filler = 0;
                    toFill = @"";     
                }
                // make it a string
                toFill = [toFill stringByAppendingFormat: @"%c",c[i]];
                if (counter_filler == 1)
                {
                     NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:toFill];
                    [scanner scanHexInt:&binar];
                    xval[xval_counter] = binar;
                    xval_counter++;
                }

                counter_filler++;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Is `characteristic.value` an `NSData` object? What is the data type of `characteristic`?

Answer (score 1):

If `characteristic.value` is actually an `NSData` object, you can replace all of your code with this:

```
uint8_t xval[20];
[characteristic.value getBytes:xval length:sizeof(xval)];
```

That's it. That will put 20 bytes from `characteristic.value` into the `xval` byte array.

`uint8_t` is an unsigned integer type that holds one 8-bit byte.

BTW - never rely on the output of an object's `description` method. When you use `stringWithFormat:` and the `%@` format specifier for an object, this results in the object's `description` method being called to get the string representation. The output of the `description` method is not documented and can change over time. Always use appropriate methods of the class to get its values.

Comment: ah, see I tried this initially but my array gets filled with UTF-8 and random numbers making me think it's not the right data structure although in the debugger it says it's nsinline

Comment: If the code in my answer runs without crashing then it is NSData and that code will put the bytes in the array as desired.